# Access denied for Administrator but security says otherwise

Tags: security, windows-server-2008-r2, files

I was removing rights to some uses on a certain folder when Windows complained that my action would restrict said user. I naturally ignored the warning since I was logged as `Administrator` and the user I was revoking rights was our third party tech remote account.

But now, `Administrator` has no longer access to that folder, even if the security tab says otherwise. I'm dumbfounded by the situation and, frankly don't know what to do.

This is the user I revoke the rights to :

[image: The revoked user]

This is the `Administrator` account and `Administrators` group :

[image: Administrator account]
[image: Administrators group]

And I am logged in as `Administrator` :

[image: Current logged in user is Administrator]

Now, when I try to access that folder, I get these :

[image: Access denied]
[image: Denied permission]

Now, why did I lose access to that folder, and how do I gain access back?

(This is me just about now.)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things.

1. Check the ownership on the folder - if it isn't set to the administrators group you can easily get that error message when attempting a permission change.
2. Verify that you aren't having issues with UAC. Use a third party explorer window (like Explorer++) launched as an administrator and try opening this folder.

Comment: Wow! Windows had set `Deny` on `OWNER`! Clicking on the "Advanced" button, I was able to change that. I'm not a Windows user, and I have to work with this because there are no IT around (I'm a dev guy) to maintain it, less the third party tech services. This does not help me find Windows security well designed... lol